# Duda con las dependencias Java 8 a Java 17 (Jasper y otras)

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8, jasper, java-17

Tengo un proyecto en Java Swing con las siguientes dependencias:

flatlaf-intellij-themes-2.4
groovy-all-2.0.1
iText-2.1.7.js2
jasperreports-5.6.0
jasperreports-applet-5.6.0
jasperreports-fonts-5.6.0
jasperreports-javaflow-5.6.0
jcalendar-1.3.3
jcalendar-1.4
jcMousePanel
jconn4
jgoodies-common-1.7.0
jgoodies-looks-2.5.3
jssc-2.8.0
jtds-1.3.1
junit-4.12
junit-4.12
liquidInf
log4j-1.2.17
mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin
mysql-connector-java-8.0.29
org-jdesktop-layout
png-encoder-1.5
poi-3.16
poi-examples-3.16
poi-excelant-3.16
poi-ooxml-3.16
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16
poi-scratchpad-3.16
sqljdbc4
xmlbeans-2.6.0

La aplicación se ejecuta con normalidad y tiene todas sus funcionalidades pero no genera el reporte, hay algun problema de compatibilidad con las librerias y la versión actual del proyecto (java 17)

Comment: Hola. Creo que `iText` es una librería alternativa a Jasper. No confundir con `iReport` que fue declarada obsoleta en el año 2015. Si quieres usar Jasper, debes usar solamente las [dependencias de Jasper Report](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports). Si quieres usar también la herramienta de diseño de reportes, considera descargar [Jasper Soft Studio](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio).

Comment: si así es pero sin embargo iText no está en uso, así que no hay problema con ello, o eso creo

Comment: No veo las [dependencias comunes](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-v6-requirements), además considera que algunas dependencias pueden tener otras dependencias. ¿Por qué tienes dos versiones distintas de mysql-connector?.